# How to set default value in checkbox of html form before submitted form in php

Tags: php

Form :

```
<tr> 
    <td>User Registration<input type="hidden" value="1" id="page[]" name="page[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="admin[]" name="admin[]" value="1" ~~CHECKED-ADMIN1~~></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="staff[]" name="staff[]" value="1" ~~CHECKED-STAFF1~~></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="member[]" name="member[]" value="1" ~~CHECKED-MEMBER1~~></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Member Registration<input type="hidden" value="2" id="page[]" name="page[]"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="admin[]" name="admin[]" value="1" ~~CHECKED-ADMIN2~~></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="staff[]" name="staff[]" value="1" ~~CHECKED-STAFF2~~></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="member[]" name="member[]" value="1" ~~CHECKED-MEMBER2~~></td>
</tr>
```

Php Code:

```
$page = $_POST['page'];
$admin = $_POST['admin'];
$staff = $_POST['staff'];
$member =$_POST['member'];
```

Now how to put default checkbox value 0 beform submitting the form in php

Comment: Two ans in this post and both  are corrected but dont know which one is suited for your question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a checkbox as `checked` from PHP or any code this is the way to do it.

```
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" id="admin[]" name="admin[]" value="1"></td>
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: if the checkbox is not checked then i put value zero in html form in array

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset()` function if you need to set checkbox post value.

```
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : array();
$admin= isset($_POST['admin']) ? $_POST['admin'] : array();
$staff = isset($_POST['staff ']) ? $_POST['staff '] : array();
$member = isset($_POST['member']) ? $_POST['member'] : array();
```

If you need to perform checkbox checked then use `checked` keyword.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="admin[]" name="admin[]" value="1" checked></td>
```

Comment: if the checkbox is not checked then i want to put zero in array 
but using this method index of array will be change

Comment: are u need something $admin= isset($_POST['admin']) ? $_POST['admin'] : array(0); ??? @pabarimohit

Comment: Yes i have convert it into array. Just define array() will solved your prob. @pabarimohit

Comment: i have multiple check box in single form and all same type of value stored in array
if i put first checkbox is not checked and second is checked then value of second checkbox is stored in index 1

Comment: You just need to check if(!empty($page)) same for $admin,$staff,$member. Its correct way to define it. @pabarimohit

Comment: please give me your error as its working fine for me. i have tested. Look here.https://eval.in/553951
Also attach your desire output so we can help you easily.

Comment: if any one use team viewer then i share my screen and to understand actual problem.

Comment: Error like this :

 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\wamp\www\AMCS\update_uti_param_access.php on line 5

Comment: $page = if(!empty($page));

Comment: This is wrong you need to write $page = isset($_POST['page']) ? $_POST['page'] : array(); then next line if(!empty($page)) { print_r($page) } else { echo "page array empty"; }. Try this @pabarimohit

Comment: this is also do not satisfy

r u using teamviewer ?

Comment: sorry. not possible TV.

Comment: R u using skype ? @RuchishParikh